# Can you create a smart contract with a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I know that you can create a new account but I am not sure if this can be done

Comment: no, setcode is not an api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Because when you deploy another smart contract it will override first one. as one blockchain can have only one smart contract.
But in future when we are playing with multichains may be at that time we will be able to do that.

But in case of inline function you can create an account with in smart contract

Comment: do u mean one account can only have one smart contract?

Comment: Yes in EOS one account can only have one smart contract.